# Force use of module name before calling function, in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I'm creating a module that I'll import in a main script. In the module, called "colors", there's a function: "info()".

colors-module:

```
def info(function=None):
    print("\ncolors\n        Info\n")
```

The problem I have, is that I may also create a function called "info()", in the main script. This won't be a problem, as long as I import the colors-module as:

```
import colors
```

If so, I would call the function in the module by writing:

```
colors.info()
```

If I instead import the module as:

```
from colors import *
```

I have two functions called the exact same.

Main script:

```
from colors import *
def info():   # A
    print("Main script's function")

info()   # A
colors.info()   # Am I able to force use of the module name before calling the
                # function, if I import the module as in this script? Can this
                # be done from the module, and not from the main script? As said,
                # force use of module name, as "colors.info()", shall only apply
                # when the module is being imported with "from colors import *".
```

**EDIT 1**

The reason why I want to import the module this way, is because of global variables in it:

```
bwc0 = (0, 0, 0)
bwc1 = (1, 1, 1)
bwc2 = (2, 2, 2)
# All the way to 255
```

After a few answers, I'll try adding these to a class, and import that class as *, if possible.
I also have a few functions in it, that I want imported as *, too. I'm not exactly sure how to import them, yet. It's probably easy, I suppose.

```
def redc(value):
    return value, 0, 0

def greenc(value):
    return 0, value, value
```

---

Thanks for all help

Comment: Using wildcards in imports is considered an anti-pattern

Comment: This would be a vary bad idea. I can only imagine all the question rolling in "Why am I unable to call function `info()` although I **explicitly** declared it in my script?". If somebody imports * ([which is bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad) anyway) and defines their own `info` function it would be absolutely horrible if this was ignored as a side-effect of another module being imported.

Comment: I would do `import colors as co`, so you have both `info()` and `co.info()`: not much longer, and it saves headaches in the long run.

Comment: The functions you just import by their names, the `buc#` globals would be best as an array: `from colors import buc, redc, greenc, bluec` then you can do `buc[0]`, `buc[1]` all the way to `buc[255]` Also as an array you have less typing in the `colors` module: `buc = [(n,n,n) for n in range(256)]`

Comment: I mainly want to import variables from the module, as *, only. If possible, I'll do so with a class, and two import statements: "import colors", and "from colors import class". See question edit for more. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't force how your function is called. If someone is writing code to call your function it's up to them to ensure that they are actually able to call it.

Either:

```
import colors
```

Or:

```
from colors import info as colors_info
```

will work if they want to call it. Otherwise they just have to avoid creating a function with a conflicting name.

BTW, as a general case don't use `from colors import *` as it means you don't know what function's you're importing. For example:

```
from colors import *
from foobar import *
```

now, is `info()` coming from `colors` or `foobar`? You can't be sure, and somewhere down the line the answer may change. So always import the names you need explicitly and that way at least they're listed in the module that uses them so you can see when conflicts will arise.

Comment: In PyCharm, which I use, I'm always notified about where a function comes from. I'm also updating my question, to tell why I want to use "from colors import *". Thanks for an answer.

Comment: @Andreas, no PyCharm will tell you where `info()` comes from while you are writing the code. But it won't tell you if the imports change when someone edits `foobar` and you don't go near your original module again. That's why it's a danger, not when you're writing the code but when things change much later after you think this code is done and dusted.

Answer (score 2):

When importing `*` from the module you won't have two functions with the same name, you'll have one function with the name `info`. Which of the two (one in `colors` or one in main script) is used depends on where the definition of `info` in main is, relative to the `from colors import *` statement.

You can't "force" the module prefix in any way; if you didn't import `colors` with `import colors` you don't have that name bound to something you can refer to.

If typing long names is the thing you're trying to avoid, just rename the `info` function you bring in from `colors` by using the `as` clause of the `from import` statement:

```
from colors import info as c_info
```

This is one of the main reasons using star `*` imports are discouraged and why namespaces are such a good idea. With `*` you throw away the separate namespace (module `colors`) that holds the name `info` function and place it in the namespace for the main script thereby masking objects with the same name.

Comment: Thanks. The reason why I want to import the module that way, is because of global variables in it. Maybe I can add them to a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the colors like a class. And the function of info is method of colors class

so, you just instant of colors and call the info() method

Comment: Adding the global color variables that I have, to a class, import everything in that class as *, and have the functions as normal, such as "colors.info()"?

Comment: Use it like
colors co
co.info()